# Render Magnolia area directly

Tags: magnolia

Is it possible to render a whole area by means of a custom URL in the browser, smth. like:

`http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/page/area` (not working)

Now we can only access particular components in that area:

`http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/page/area/0` or
`http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/page/area/00`

We'd like to render the area together will all components and couldn't find any reference to such a case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Magnolia's documentation has a [page](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Rendering+content#Renderingcontent-Directcomponentrendering) on this:

> ... the opener area of the /demo-project/about page rendered by the URL ... /magnoliaAuthor/demo-project/about~mgnlArea=opener~.html.

But only works with Freemarker.

Comment: I had made the experience that although Magnolia claims that you can use JSP as your templating language, it has a much better support for Freemarker. If you are in an early stage of your project with only a few pages, it probably will be worth the effort to convert them into Freemarker templates.

Comment: Right, I turned our Magnolia templates to flt.

Comment: Yes, direct area rendering works just for Freemarker, direct component rendering works fine for both. The problem is that you can't easily highjack output stream for jsp and redirect it elsewhere.

HTH,
Jan